# Automatically add the date in a cell based off text in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to add the date into a cell only when another cell has "closed" in it. If it has anything else in it I need it to be clear.

I'm using a drop down that has only two options "Open" & "Closed". When I select "Closed" I want the cell to the right to insert the current date.

I found some VBA code that will let me add the date no matter what code is in the cell but I can't figure it out.

I also found the following works but I have to place it in every cell down one column.

```
=IF(AND(F2<>"",F2<>"Open"),TODAY(),"")
```

This is what code that would add the date no matter what data was in the cell

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
On Error Resume Next
If (Target.Count = 1) Then
    If (Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B:B")) Is Nothing) Then _
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set xRg = Application.Intersect(Target.Dependents, Me.Range("B:B"))
    If (Not xRg Is Nothing) Then
        For Each xCell In xRg
            xCell.Offset(0, -1) = Date
        Next
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you realize that tomorrow the TODAY() function will be different from what is showing today?

Comment: Can you provide the VBA?

Comment: @Jeeped I did not. So you are saying when I open the sheet tomorrow those dates will change to the current date?

Comment: @Zac I edited the original question to include the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fairly boilerplate Worksheet_Change that will put in the date permanently.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F:F")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim rw As Long, rng As Range
        For Each rng In Intersect(Target, Range("F:F"))
            Select Case LCase(rng.Value2)
                Case "closed"
                    rng.Offset(0, 1) = Date
                    'optional date formatting
                    'rng.Offset(0, 1).numberformat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"
                Case Else
                    rng.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
            End Select
        Next rng
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    If CBool(Val(Err.Number)) Then _
        Debug.Print Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

This belongs in the worksheet's code sheet, **not** a standard module. It should survive multiple deletions, edits and/or additions.

Comment: This works just as I was needing. Thank You so much! I searched and searched and couldn't find it.

Comment: Next time, just look through my answers (LOL :D). This came (with very minor modification) from another question I replied to. The search terms you are looking for would be *vba timestamp*.

Comment: Will do! Thanks again.